# ORM relations and lacking a better understanding

Tags: silverstripe

I have the following models

- `Genres` (can have one or more movies)
- `Movies` (can have one or more genres or production companies
- `ProductionCompanies` (can have many movies)

I just can't work out if I should be using `has_many` or `many_many`.

#### My attempt

**Genres**

```
<?php

class Genres extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        "GenreId" => "Int",
        "Name" => "Varchar"
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        "Movies" => "Movie"
    );
}
```

**Movies**

```
<?php
class Movies extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        "Status" => "Varchar",
        "Tagline" => "Varchar",
        "Title" => "Varchar",
        "Video" => "Varchar",
        "VoteAverage" => "Decimal",
        "VoteCount" => "Int"
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        "ProductionCompanies" => "ProductionCompany",
        "Genres" => "Genre"
    );

}
```

**ProductionCompanies**

```
<?php

class ProductionCompanies extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        "CompanyId" => "Int",
        "Description" => "Text",
        "Headquarters" => "Varchar",
        "Homepage" => "Varchar",
        "LogoPath" => "Varchar",
        "Name" => "Varchar",
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        "Movies" => "Movie"
    );
}
```

The docs state:

> Please specify a $has_one-relationship on the related child-class as well, in order to have the necessary accessors available on both ends.

But my misunderstanding here is that none of my models "has one", they all have many

I want to show a list of Genres which within has a list of Movies associated with that Genre

I also want a list of Production Companies which within has a list of Movies associated with that company.

And I also want a movie to be able to associate with one or more genre and/or production company.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’ll want a many-to-many here:

```
<?php

class Genre extends DataObject {
    private static $many_many = array(
        'Movies' => 'Movie'
    );
}

class Movie extends DataObject {
    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Genres' => 'Genre',
        'ProductionCompanies' => 'ProductionCompany'
    );
}

class ProductionCompany extends DataObject {
    private static $many_many = array(
        'Movies' => 'Movie'
    );
}
```

If both sides can "have many" of each other, then you'll need many-to-many. has-many only applies if one side of the relationship can only ever be related to *one* of the other side.

The docs explain when it’s best to use many_many or belongs_many_many: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/model/relations/#many-many-or-belongs-many-many. I’ve completely ignored them and done the opposite :D (because a movie *belongs* to a production company, not the other way around). The distinction isn’t too important, as long as one side has a many_many it will work - regardless of *which* side it’s on.

Comment: Also note how kinglozzer names the classes. Don't think the class as a holder but as an entity.

Comment: Forgot to add this link on the comment https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/working-with-data-relationships-many-many . There are own videos for other relation types also.

Comment: I've been there of course, guess it's just easier to understand when it applies to the scenario you got stuck in your head. Thanks for the clarity to you both

Comment: Note that you dont have to add the primary KEY to your classes: eg these are unnecessary "GenreId" => "Int" and "CompanyId" => "Int" as the ORM adds by default a primary key.

Comment: Yeah, these ID's however come from an external API and are not sequential, and they're needed in further requests down the track

Comment: If they are external values Id suggest on naming them with Ex or just commenting that they are external :D.. Makes it obvious for the next coder ;)

Comment: Duely noted on the naming convention tip thanks FinBoWa!